# How to use ListView and stop element from scrolling?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a screen with a `ListView` that holds an SVG, `Stack` and `TextField`s. When the keyboard is opened, I get the usual `Overflow` error so I'm using a `ListView` to combat it since I'm using a `Column` anyway.

I want my SVG image to stay fixed at the top while the rest scrolls underneath it, anyway to give the image a fixed position?

```
child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  SvgPicture.asset( //Should stay fixed while rest scroll
                    'assets/example.svg',
                    color: primaryColor,
                    height: 80.0,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  Center(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        _image != null
                            ? InkWell(
                          onTap: selectImage,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 48,
                            backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                          ),
                        )
                            : InkWell(
                          onTap: selectImage,
                          child: const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 48,
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/user.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: -10,
                          left: 50,
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: selectImage,
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 50),
                  TextFieldInput(...),
                  TextFieldInput(...),
                  TextFieldInput(...),
                  TextFieldInput(...)...
```

I've tried taking the SVG out of the `Column` and changing the `ListView` into a `Column` with a `SingleChildScrollView` parent and I still get `Render Overflow`. Code follows:

```
child: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/example.svg',
            color: primaryColor,
            height: 80.0,
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    Center(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          _image != null
                              ? InkWell(
                                  onTap: selectImage,
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 48,
                                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : InkWell(
                                  onTap: selectImage,
                                  child: const CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 48,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        AssetImage('assets/user.png'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: -10,
                            left: 50,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: selectImage,
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    TextFieldInput(..),
                    TextFieldInput(..),
                    TextFieldInput(..)...
```

What would be the correct approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `SingleChildScrollView` in a `Expanded` widget, like this:

```
child: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/example.svg',
            color: primaryColor,
            height: 80.0,
          ),
          Expanded( //<--- add this
           child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    Center(
                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          _image != null
                              ? InkWell(
                                  onTap: selectImage,
                                  child: CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 48,
                                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage(_image!),
                                  ),
                                )
                              : InkWell(
                                  onTap: selectImage,
                                  child: const CircleAvatar(
                                    radius: 48,
                                    backgroundImage:
                                        AssetImage('assets/user.png'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: -10,
                            left: 50,
                            child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: selectImage,
                              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 50),
                    TextFieldInput(..),
                    TextFieldInput(..),
                    TextFieldInput(..)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Column by default has **screen height** size that is why you get render flow error when screen size increases because you're not making **topmost column scrollable**.

there are 2 possible solution you can do

1. Wrap your **singleChildScrollView** inside **Expanded**. It will adjust and scroll your all items inside remaining space after image.
2. Make your **topmost column scrollable** by wrapping inside **SingleChildScrollView**. It will solve render flow error issue but your screen whole screen will scroll as well.